# How to output object of an array in the root of the document in MongoDB using aggregation?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I have this document :

```
{"_id":"1", "elem":"ok",
   "arrayOfObjects":[
                     {"type":"k","fieldx":"lol"},
                     {"type":"SndObject","fieldy":"foo"},
                     {"type":"Object1","fieldx":"bob"}
                    ]
}
```

what is the aggregation to have this output:

```
{"_id":"1", "elem":"ok",
"Object1":[
          {"type":"Object1","fieldx":"lol"},
          {"type":"Object1","fieldx":"bob"}
          ],
 "SndObject":[{"type":"SndObject","fieldy":"foo"}]
}
```

I found a way out, but it need me to know all the type i have:

```
{ 
  "$addFields" : { 
    "Object1" : { 
      "$filter": { 
        "input": "$arrayOfObjects", 
        "as": "types", 
        "cond": { 
          "$and": [{ "$eq": [ "$$types.type", "Object1" ] }] 
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

It would be best if i can loop over my `arrayOfObjects` and get the same result without pre knowledge of the type.

Comment: Hi, it's a little unclear what you are trying to do. The result data you have listed seems arbitrarily assembled from the document, but best I can guess, you want to get all results grouped by `"type"`, correct? Please clarify, and format your code.

Comment: Hi Connor Low thank you so much, i want to group the same types in a new array and put that array in the root of the document; i found a way out, but it need me to know all the type i have: {
   "$addFields" : {
       "Object1" : { "$filter": { "input": "$arrayOfObjects", "as": "types", "cond": { "$and": [{ "$eq": [ "$$types.type", "Object1" ] }] }} }] 

It would be best if i can loop over my arrayOfObjects and get the same result without  pre knowledge of the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be there would be more easy option than this,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `arrayOfObjects` array
- `$group` by `_id, type and elem`, construct array of `arrayOfObjects`
- `$arrayToObject` convert k and v from array to object
- `$group` by `_id` and merge objects in root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$arrayOfObjects" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        type: "$arrayOfObjects.type",
        _id: "$_id"
      },
      elem: { $first: "$elem" },
      arrayOfObjects: { $push: "$arrayOfObjects" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      elem: { $first: "$elem" },
      arrayOfObjects: { 
        $mergeObjects: {
          $arrayToObject: [[
              {
                k: "$_id.type",
                v: "$arrayOfObjects"
              }
          ]]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OAJANu6imTf)